# the error of using conda install from anaconda channel or the downloaded package

Tags: conda

I was trying to conda install the python package of hdmedians

[image]

I tried different channels list on [the related anaconda page](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/hdmedians), All of them gave the same above message. Then, I was trying to install the hdmedians package directly downloaded from Anaconda cloud, here is the conda install result, which seems finishes successfully. But when I try to input it, it still cannot import related module

```
(ver) PS C:\Users> conda install C:\Users\Downloads\hdmedians-0.14.2-py38h71d37f0_2.tar.bz2

Downloading and Extracting Packages
###################################################################################################### | 100%
Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: done
(ver) PS C:\Users> python
Python 3.8.13 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Mar 25 2022, 05:59:45) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import hdmedians as hd

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'hdmedians'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`hdmedians` is only available for non-Windows OS from any public conda channel, see [here](https://anaconda.org/search?q=+hdmedians+) (notice the Platforms column). That is why it is not found when doing `conda install hdmedians`.

Whatever file you have downloaded, it is not compiled for your system, so you cannot expect it to work.
How `conda` handles this case though seems to be odd, as it does not produce any error message or similar. I tried it and it even lists `hdmedians` in `conda list`, but has not copied anything into `site-packages`.

But apart from that confusion, the main issue is still that you will not get a version compatible with windows from `conda` channels

Comment: thanks, I tried pip install, and it is working now. Are there any packages, having the similar functionality of hdmedian, which can work well for conda install on windows? Thanks.